# Drupal 7 Views exposed filter "Any" with limited selection

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, filtering, drupal-views

I'm having an issue with the Drupal 7 `-Any-` option in an exposed filter. I have a list of about 8 taxonomy terms and I want my users to be able to filter between 6 of them. The other 2 terms are used in another place on the website, but all 8 are part of the same vocabulary.

My taxonomy terms are (for example):

```
Eggs
Ham
Cheese
Bacon
Sausage
Juice
Fruit
Toast
```

In my exposed filter I have 6 of those terms selected as available options to filter between. Right now the filter looks like this:

```
-Any-
Eggs
Ham
Cheese
Bacon
Sausage
Juice
```

The problem is that when you select `-Any-` it includes the `Toast` and `Fruit` terms. I would like `-Any-` to only be any of the 6 terms I selected in the View.

One workaround is to check the `Required` box to require that a selection is made. This turns off the `-Any-` option, but I'd like to keep it so the default selection displays all 6 items when you get to the page.

How do I limit `-Any-` to only include my selections for the exposed filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also add another filter for the same taxonomy vocabulary. Do not expose it, set the operator to "Is none of" and select the terms you do not want searched (Fruit,Toast).

So that way, even when your users choose "any" from the exposed filter, the unexposed filter will remove any of the unwanted terms.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was trying to do but it was being pretty buggy. Eventually I tried using the taxonomy terms with depth and that made it work. Not really sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_views_query_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) and add another where clause to restrict it to the list.